# Spin groups in terms of matrices and/or linear operators

Tags: reference-request, matrices, lie-groups, spin-geometry

Thus far, the books and articles I have read dealing with spin groups $\mathbf{Spin}(n)$ and $\mathbf{Spin}(p,q)$ consider them only in terms of either Clifford algebras or topologically as the double covers, respectively, of the special orthogonal groups $\mathbf{SO}(n)$ and $\mathbf{SO}(p,q)$. The spin groups are Lie groups, and I'm aware that there are exceptional isomorphisms between some of them and a few matrix groups. But my question is in general, can $\mathbf{Spin}(n)$ and $\mathbf{Spin}(p,q)$ be viewed just in terms of matrices and/or linear operators? If so, what are some good references that might be able to help in answering this question?

Comment: The right thing to google is "spin representation", which provides a natural way to view the spin groups as matrix groups.  There are a number of ways to construct the spin representations, but normally one views $Spin(n)$ as a subgroup of the Clifford algebra on $n$ generators and constructs a representation of the Clifford algebra on an exterior algebra.  Studying these representations carefully yields the exceptional isomorphisms that you alluded to.  The wikipedia page on the spin representation has a lot of detail; otherwise check out Lawson-Michelsohn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spin groups are algebraic and so they can be presented as subgroups of general linear group that is defined by a system of algebraic equations. You can find one possible presentation in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/138179/6818) on MO.